# WP Genesis framework : how to display the primary sidebar manually?

Tags: wordpress, templates, frameworks

I need to display the primary sidebar in my home.php template (WordPress Genesis Framework). What is the code to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

For the primary sidebar in genesis you need

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar'); ?>
```

for the secondary sidebar

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar('alt-sidebar'); ?>
```

For anything else it is custom per the theme (what ever came with that theme, or whatever you ad

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar('your-sidebar-name/id'); ?>
```

Comment: Sure but how can I know the name of the sidebar ? It's not visible in the WP dashboard widget page and I can't find it in Genesis' function.php either.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php do_action( 'genesis_sidebar_alt' ); ?>
```